# Retrieve catkin build artificat path

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm building my first C++ ROS static library using Catkin, and I would like to link that library into an existing application which is being built with a Makefile.
So I would like to know if there is a way to use a ROS or Catkin command to retrieve the path of the built library and so I will not have to hardcode the path of the library in the -L flag.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224744/retrieve-catkin-build-artificat-path/) by [LiohAu](https://answers.ros.org/users/22186/liohau/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2016-01-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think `catkin_find` is what you are looking at. `catkin_find --help` will tell you how to use it.

---

Originally posted by [Dimitri Schachmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/22775/dimitri-schachmann/) with karma: 789 on 2016-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [LiohAu](https://answers.ros.org/users/22186/liohau/) on 2016-01-22**:
catkin_find --lib --first-only seems to be what I was looking for, even if I have to source my workspace setup.bash from my Makefile first :(
One more question, my devel/ folder contains the "lib" directory, but no "include" directory, any idea of why my library .h are not being copied ?